# Terminal Freezes after roslaunch event

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3at, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to spawn a pioneer3at robot in gazebo through ros so I created a file called p3at.launch and made the corresponding urdf file. When I roslaunch it, it started normally but freezes. Terminal looks like this -

//Terminal

```
arpit@arpit-SVE15137CNB:/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf$ roslaunch gazebo_ros p3at.launch

... logging to /home/arpit/.ros/log/ee1fb8ae-5bcf-11e5-97ce-b8763fea9d09/roslaunch-arpit-SVE15137CNB-16521.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://arpit-SVE15137CNB:54185/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS

 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13

NODES
 
 /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)


auto-starting new master

process[master]: started with pid [16536]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to ee1fb8ae-5bcf-11e5-97ce-b8763fea9d09
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16549]
started core service [/rosout]
process[spawn_urdf-2]: started with pid [16566]
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [16567]
```

And here is the launch file

```
  <launch>
  <env name="GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH" value="$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/.gazebo/models" />
  <env name="GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH" value="$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH:~/.gazebo/models" />

  <arg name="world" default="worlds/empty.world" />

  <arg name="urdf" default="$(find urdf)/pioneer3at.urdf" />
  <arg name="name" default="pioneer3at" />
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg urdf)" />
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model $(arg name)" /> 
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

  </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217708/terminal-freezes-after-roslaunch-event/) by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-15**:
That looks normal. What do you expect it to do?

**Comment by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on 2015-09-15**:
It does not launch the gazebo simulator with the p3at robot. It is not doing anything after this whereas the other launch files are launched in the gazebo simulator.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-09-15**:
May be your processor is slow or less RAM. What is your processor and how much RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your launch file doesn't include an instance of gazebo; only the spawner, which expects to connect to gazebo.

If you want to solve this on your own, compare your launch file to an existing launch file that behaves the way you expect, with a different robot.

If you want more help, please edit your question to include the launch file that you've written.

**EDIT**

Your launch file does not start gazebo.

You can start gazebo by adding the following include to your launch file:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on 2015-09-15**:
Yeah! Thanks !! :)

**Comment by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on 2021-09-26**:
Thanks it worked